# Calculating Average per hour for Zoo object

Tags: r, xts, zoo

I have the following:

```
Lines <- "D1,Diff
1,20/11/2014 16:00,0.01
2,20/11/2014 17:00,0.02
3,20/11/2014 18:00,0.03
4,21/11/2014 16:00,0.04
5,21/11/2014 17:00,0.06
6,21/11/2014 18:00,0.07"

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep = ",")
ep <- endpoints(z,'hours')
a<-period.apply(z,ep,mean)
```

I would like to create a new Zoo object that for each hour there will be the average of Diff of the same hour. The required result will be:

```
16:00,0.025
17:00,0.03
18:00,0.05
```

The content of a:

```
> a
    2014-11-20 16:00:00 2014-11-20 17:00:00 2014-11-20 18:00:00 2014-11-21 16:00:00 2014-11-21 17:00:00 2014-11-21 18:00:00 
                   0.01                0.02                0.03                0.04                0.06                0.07
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Zoo Object:

   > b<-aggregate(z, hour(index(z)), mean)
   >   b
   >      16    17    18 
   >   0.025 0.040 0.050 
   >   class (b)
   >   [1] "zoo"
2. Transformation to dataframe:

   > a<-aggregate(z ~ hour(index(z)), FUN = 'mean')
   >   a
   >     hour(index(z))     z
   >   1             16 0.025
   >   2             17 0.040
   >   3             18 0.050
   >   class (a)
   >   [1] "data.frame"